# Highcharts - "Archery Range" chart?

Tags: highcharts

What chart I should choose to make "Archery Range" chart (stacked circles chart)? I.e. central area is highest score, next circle a bit less, etc.

I think Polar chart is most close, but maybe more exact match exists?

[image: Archery Range chart]

Tags: archery range chart, dart chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just show circles, maybe you can use pie chart?

```
series: [{
  name: 'outer',
  data: [1],
  size: '60%',
  borderColor: null,
  color: 'green',
  colorByPoint: false,
}, {
  name: 'middle',
  data: [1],
  size: '80%',
  innerSize: '60%',
  color: 'red',
  colorByPoint: false,
  borderColor: null,
  borderWidth: 1
}, {
  name: 'inner',
  data: [1],
  size: '20%',
  color: 'blue',
  colorByPoint: false,
  borderColor: null,
  borderWidth: 1
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8fec7zao/2/

If you want to show points on your chart as well, polar chart will be the best idea. Here you can find an example how it can work:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      polar: true
    },
    pane: {
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: 360
    },
    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 8,
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 12,
      tickInterval: 4,
      plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 4,
        color: 'green',
      }, {
        from: 4,
        to: 8,
        color: 'yellow',
      }, {
        from: 8,
        to: 12,
        color: 'red',
      }]
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'scatter',
      color: 'black',
      data: [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [2.4, 6]
      ],
    }]
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rsLnxL04/

Comment: Pie Chart is more close. Because it has highlighting when hovering over sections. But it doesn't have labels like 15, 10, 5. Thank you, very much, I will configure remaining parts myself.

Comment: Also Gauge chart possibly will work, but dunno how to show dataLabels in it. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/  And nevertheless I'm already implemented task using your pie chart, thank you.